# GraphQL, Relay and Mongodb (mongoose) how to fetch array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

I can't fetch array or object with mongoose to use it in Relay connection, actually this works fine:

```
let queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: () => ({
        getUsers: {
            type: new GraphQLList(userType),
            resolve: (_, args) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    Users.find(args, (err, users) => {
                        err ? reject(err) : resolve(users);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    })
});
```

in GraphiQL i can get array. But when I try use the same "resolve" function with Relay it doesn't work!

```
getUsers: {
    node: nodeField,
    type: usersType,
    resolve: (_, args) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Users.find(args, (err, users) => {
                err ? reject(err) : resolve(users);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

and I think reason is because Users.find() return Promise instead of Array or Obj.
Same function if  I just change "Users.find()" to any other function with return array works fine.

So main question how can I get array or object with "Users.find()" instead of Promise? (,lean(), .exec()) doesn't help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm i graphql-relay-connection --save
const {connectionFromPromisedArray} = mongooseConnection;
```

and instead of `connectionFromArray(get(), args)` we can pass Promise: `connectionFromPromisedArray(collection.find(), args)`

Finally you can fetch array from Promise without tons of code.